# Reshaping and stacking a 2D array to form a 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

I have a dataframe as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,2,2,2], 
                   'b': [10, 20, 30, 20, 40, 60],
                  'c': [80, 80, 80, 120, 120, 120]})
```

I want to get 3D array

```
array([[[  1,  10,  80],
       [  2,  20, 120] ],

       [[  1,  20,  80] ,
       [  2,  40, 120] ],

       [[  1,  30,  80],
        [  2,  60, 120]]], dtype=int64)
```

I do like this

```
values = df.values
values.reshape(3, 2, 3)
```

and get an incorrect array. How to get the expected array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the array data, then reshape splitting the first axis into two with the first of them being of length `2` giving us a `3D` array and then swap those two axes -

```
df.values.reshape(2,-1,df.shape[1]).swapaxes(0,1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [711]: df
Out[711]: 
   a   b    c
0  1  10   80
1  1  20   80
2  1  30   80
3  2  20  120
4  2  40  120
5  2  60  120

In [713]: df.values.reshape(2,-1,df.shape[1]).swapaxes(0,1)
Out[713]: 
array([[[  1,  10,  80],
        [  2,  20, 120]],

       [[  1,  20,  80],
        [  2,  40, 120]],

       [[  1,  30,  80],
        [  2,  60, 120]]])
```

This gives us a view into the original data without making a copy and as such has a minimal constant time.

**Runtime test**

Case #1 :

```
In [730]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,(2000,100)))

# @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's soln
In [731]: %timeit np.stack(np.split(df.values, 2), axis=1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 109 µs per loop

In [732]: %timeit df.values.reshape(2,-1,df.shape[1]).swapaxes(0,1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.55 µs per loop
```

Case #2 :

```
In [733]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,(2000,2000)))

# @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's soln
In [734]: %timeit np.stack(np.split(df.values, 2), axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.3 ms per loop

In [735]: %timeit df.values.reshape(2,-1,df.shape[1]).swapaxes(0,1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.37 µs per loop
```

Comment: Always knew yours was going to be faster. ;-) +1

Answer (score 3):

Try `np.split` + `np.stack`:

```
np.stack(np.split(df.values, 2), axis=1)

array([[[  1,  10,  80],
        [  2,  20, 120]],

       [[  1,  20,  80],
        [  2,  40, 120]],

       [[  1,  30,  80],
        [  2,  60, 120]]])
```